# Training a model to predict duplicate records in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, svm

I have the adjustment data in telecom domain: There are problems that sometimes the automation script generates the bill twice which causes duplicate records.

I want to know how to prepare the data and train the ML model. Currently, I am considering the duplicate record as issues and training the SVM model for one-class classification.

```
Duplicate Bill
    ABC13C,13.59,2017-03-01,2017-03-01,2017-03-01,118,I,A,0,C,2011    1
```

Should I train the model with actual bill and duplicate bill as both issues and train the model and then predict the rest or is there any other way to consider or should I implement time-series classification?

```
Records 
Actual Bill                                                     label
ABC13C,13.59,2017-03-01,2017-03-01,2017-03-01,118,I,A,0,C,2011    1
Duplicate Bill
ABC13C,13.59,2017-03-01,2017-03-01,2017-03-01,118,I,A,0,C,2011    1
```

Comment: Look into _deduplication_ or _record linkage_. This is a classic problem in _information retrieval_.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't a machine learning task, but a database task. Unless you want indication why such records appear as duplicates, but that is more of a debugging task.

Comment: Do you think I am not aware of that?

Comment: Then please explain why you consider this a machine learning task. Maybe I am missing some subtle point in your question. Or there is some domain knowledge that is more obvious for you than for me.